Prevent refs from being unwrapped when passed to functions
I have a ref:
const day = ref(null);

I have an input:
   <input v-model="day" class="border p-2" @blur="pad(day)" />

I have a pad method:
const pad = (day) => {
    //day is the value (e.g. 7) and not a reference to the ref
    ....

Inside pad i want to pass the day ref and modify it like day.value = '2312' but the value is already unwrapped.
Any way to prevent this?
I have tried:
   <input v-model="day" class="border p-2" @blur="pad(ref(day))" />

But this creates a new ref and does not reference the original value.

I don't know of a way of preventing unwrapping. Instead, you could try @blur="day = pad(day)" and make pad return the padded date? Otherwise, Alexander's answer works too.

Yes, this is a problem of no way to pass a top level unwrapped ref, but you can use the ref directly:
Playground
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const day = ref('')
function pad(){
  day.value = day.value.padStart(2, '0');
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ day }}</h1>
  <input v-model="day" @blur="pad" />
</template>

Btw, the unwrapped ref does work also, but the first example is more clear/semantic since the extra ref passing logic is removed.
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const day = ref('')
function pad(val){
  day.value = val.padStart(2, '0');
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ day }}</h1>
  <input v-model="day" @blur="pad(day)" />
</template>

